# Multisite/Multidomain and headless mode

Tags: multi-site, multi-environment, headless

Our company has two websites. Both sites were build independently with Craft CMS. One site uses Twig templates, the other operates in headless mode. Is it possible to „mix“ them in one Craft system, as a multi-site/multi-domain environment or do we first have to change all sites to headless mode?

Kind regards Matthias